# Allow DialogFlow's response time for web-service-fulfillment to be greater than 5 seconds

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

According to [Dialogflow Docs](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/docs/fulfillment-webhook)

The response must occur within 10 seconds for Google Assistant applications or 5 seconds for all other applications, otherwise, the request will time out.

Is there any way we can increase this without going for an API WebClient approach?

I am using the **dialogflow web demo** as web client and need to make a call to node service to fetch data from a cloud dB.

Answer (score 0):

**The following limitations apply to your response:**

- The response must occur within 10 seconds for Google Assistant
  applications or 5 seconds for all other applications, otherwise the
  request will time out.
- The response must be less than or equal to 64 KiB in size.

How ever there will be,

> Webhook call failed. Error: DEADLINE_EXCEEDED

So you must complate your task within 5 second. and if you are not able to fetch data within 5 second then there is something wrong with your infrastructure.